# Can't pass php variable to JS which then calls php file to update sql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm having trouble fixing this. I want to pass a php variable to some JS. The JS then calls a php file using the php variable. In this case domain.com/updatesql.php?userid=*USERNAME*.

Here is my index.php which does pass the userid to fixer.php ok.

```
//////////////////Index.php////////////////////
<?php
$err_msg = '';

if( isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if($_POST['userid'] == '')
    {
        $err_msg = 'Please enter userid<br>';
    }

   if($err_msg == '')
   {
            $data_frm = '<form name="frm1" id="frm1" action="fixer.php" method="get">
            <input type="hidden"  name="userid" id="userid" value="'.$_POST['userid'].'">
            </form>';
        echo $data_frm.=" <script language='Javascript'> document.frm1.submit();</script>";
   }
}
?>

<div id="signup">
     <form method="post" method="frm" id="frm" >
        <p class="form-field"><div align="center">

         <input type="text" size="46" name="userid" id="userid" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['userid'])) echo $_POST['userid']; ?>" placeholder="Your userid" />
        </p>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <p class="form-submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit userid" >
</div>
        </p>
    </form>
```

Userid does get passed to fixer.php from index.php. This JS doesn't successfully pass the userid to the url /updatesql.php (well the SQL isn't being updated anyway)

```
//////////////fixer.php//////////////// 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething2(){
        $.ajax
            { url: '/updatesql.php',
                data: { userid : <?php echo $subid ?> },
                type : 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function ( jsXHR) {
                },
                failed : function(status,data){ }
               }
         );
    }

;
</script>
        <?php   $subid = $_GET['userid']; ?>


<input type='button' id='countdw' value='Wait 3s'  class='btn btn-primary disabled'>


        <script>
            var secsLeft = 3;
            setInterval(function(){
                secsLeft--;
                if(secsLeft > 0){
                    $('#countdw').val('Wait ' + secsLeft + 's');
                } else if(secsLeft == 0){
                    $('#countdw').removeClass('disabled');
                    $('#countdw').val('NEXT');
                     $('#countdw').attr("onclick","doSomething2()"); 

                }
            }, 1000);


        </script>
```

And here is the php to update the SQL. I'm aware it's not mysqli and I need to update/get a new book. Thank you for any help!

```
////////////////////////////////updatesql.php////////////////////    
    <?php
      include("config.php");
    include("mysql.php");
                        $reward = 20;
    $subid   = $_GET['userid'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE ".MYSQLTABLE." SET amount=amount+".$reward." WHERE userid='".$subid."'") or die(mysql_error());

     mysql_close();

     ?>
```

Comment: you are calling `<?php $subid ?>` before defining `$subid = $_GET['userid'];`, plus you need it to be `<?php echo $subid ?>`

Comment: Still having an issue with it. It did originally have the echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you, Fix your php `echo` and then see what your `GET` array contains? try to do this way

//fixer.php

```
<?php   $subid = $_GET['userid']; ?> //but set your $subid first
```

//js function

```
function doSomething2(){
        $.ajax
            { url: '/updatesql.php',
                data: { userid : <?php echo $subid; ?> },  //you missed echo here
                type : 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function (jsXHR) {
                 // console.log('success');
                },
                failed : function(status,data){ 
                 //console.log('error');     
                 }
               }
         );
    }
```

//on updatesql.php , for debug purpose

```
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($_GET);
 echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things wrong, firstly you're trying to use `$subid` in your JavaScript before defining it. You need to do `$subid   = $_GET['userid'];` before your JavaScript.

Secondly you have `<?php $subid ?>`, which does absolutely nothing. You need to echo out the PHP so when the page loads it's a variable in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, I have made the amendments but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have several alert of security concerns about your code. First all never print user content directly to browser. And never use SQL directly, concatenated values from users.